# What is prefetchSize in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

In RabbitMQ tutorial, there is such code:

```
channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);
```

I understand what's `prefetchCount` and `global`, but not `prefetchSize`.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 12):

I found this in the protocol reference https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html (emphasis mine):

> long prefetch-size
>
> The client can request that messages be sent in advance so that when
>   the client finishes processing a message, the following message is
>   already held locally, rather than needing to be sent down the channel.
>   Prefetching gives a performance improvement. This field specifies the
>   prefetch window size in octets. **The server will send a message in
>   advance if it is equal to or smaller in size than the available
>   prefetch size** (and also falls into other prefetch limits). May be set
>   to zero, meaning "no specific limit", although other prefetch limits
>   may still apply. The prefetch-size is ignored if the no-ack option is
>   set.
>
> The server MUST ignore this setting when the client is not processing any messages - i.e. the prefetch size does not limit the
>   transfer of single messages to a client, only the sending in advance
>   of more messages while the client still has one or more unacknowledged
>   messages.

Comment: Looks like prefetch size limits are not implemented by RabbitMQ https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html#method-status-basic.qos

Answer (score 1):

`prefetchSize`：  maximum amount of content (measured in
octets) that the server will deliver, 0 if unlimited.

`prefetchCount`:  maximum number of messages that the server will deliver, 0 if unlimited.

`count` means you set the limit based on the numbers of messages while `size` means set the limit based on the actual message content size.